# how do you convert a list into a int in python in one/two lines?

Tags: python, list, loops, integer

If you want to convert a list into a int

You could use

```
x = ""
the_list = [5,7,8,6]
for integer in the_list:
       x+=str(integer)
ans = int(x)
#output
5786
```

is there a shorter way for doing this?
Thanks for helping

Comment: What is `the_list`? Please read how to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` has a `join` method, where it takes a list as an argument and joins each element by given string.

For example you can create a comma separated line  as such:

```
the_list = ["foo", "bar"]
print(",".join(the_list))
```

result:

```
foo,bar
```

Remember, all elements of the list must be strings. So you should map it first:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(int("".join(map(str, the_list))))
```

result:

```
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is in the form: `[1,5,3,11]`

You can use:

```py
lst = [1, 5, 3, 11]
x = int("".join([str(x) for x in lst]))
```

```
>>> x
15311
```

Answer (score 1):

what you could do for this is use list comprehension to turn your list of values into a list of strings. Then you could use the `.join` method to join the list of strings together. For example:

```
string_list = [str(num) for num in list]
integer = "".join(string_list)
```

An example with a list:

```
list = [3, 4, 5]

string_list = [str(num) for num in list]
integer = "".join(string_list)

print(integer)
```

Output:
`345`

The `.join()` method allows you do combine string list values together with your desired character being specified in the "" quotation marks. List comprehension is a shortcut to make a for loop inside of a list.

Comment: you have to change the variable 'list' into something else or the list function would be override and could not be used later.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. The variable `list` will still equal to `[3, 4, 5]`. It was not overridden since the string version of the list is stored in `string_list`.

Comment: what I mean is if you use the name 'list' for that variable you can't use it in the future because it was ovveridded

Comment: It wasn't overwritten. It is still the same `list = [3, 4, 5]`. Could you specify where you think it was overwritten?

Comment: I mean that not the variable list got overridden but the function list got overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum()` function will sum all elements in the list.

Example:

```
ints = [1, 3, 5, 7]
print(sum(ints, 0))
```

Where 0 is the starting index, and ints is your list (not required)